# Adding a default icon to a dynamically generated .NET assembly

Tags: c#, .net, icons, .net-assembly, explorer

I am generating a .NET assembly dynamically and adding resources to it using two different methods:

- ModuleBuilder.DefineResource
- AssemblyBuilder.DefineResource

One of the resources is an icon (the only icon added to the assembly) and I want this icon to show up as the default icon of the executable in Windows Explorer. Using the following code, the resource is embedded fine and is accessible but does not show up as the default icon of the executable in Windows Explorer.

```
using (var writerIcon = moduleBuilder.DefineResource(nameAssembly.Name + ".Resources.IconMain", "Application resources.", ResourceAttributes.Public))
{
    using (var icon = new Icon(@"Icon.ico"))
    {
        writerIcon.AddResource("Main.ico", icon);
    }

    builderAssembly.Save(@"MyPE.exe", PortableExecutableKinds.ILOnly, ImageFileMachine.I386);
}
```

**OR**

```
using (var writer = assemblyBuilder.DefineResource(nameAssembly.Name + ".Resources.IconMain", "Application resources.", nameAssembly.Name + ".Resources.IconMain", ResourceAttributes.Public))
{
    using (var icon = new Icon(@"Icon.ico"))
    {
        writerIcon.AddResource("Main.ico", icon);
    }

    builderAssembly.Save(@"MyPE.exe", PortableExecutableKinds.ILOnly, ImageFileMachine.I386);
}
```

I know that .NET assemblies handle resources differently then native PEs but I'm not sure that is relevant. Bottom line is, I do not see a way to specify this through code.

In Visual Studio, you can specify an assembly icon and I want to achieve exactly that from managed code (via P/Invoke if necessary). Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: The icon for an assembly is specified with the /win32icon C# compiler option.  AssemblyBuilder has nothing similar.  Monkeying with the UpdateResource() winapi function is something I never advice.  Only reasonable approach is to use a little bootstrapper .exe file that doesn't do anything but load your generated assembly.  It can store the icon.  You can autogenerate it with System.CodeDom, CompilerParameters.CompileOptions property.

Comment: @HansPassant: That's a shame. I've read your answers on issues with `UpdateResource` and failed at making it work. Since the app won't have access to a compiler, a bootstrapper using CodeDom seems like the only managed approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using CodeDom instead of dynamic assembly generation. Not a personal preference but it gave me more control over resources and assembly generation options by specifying arguments to the compiler.